# Properties wont work in UIView class

Tags: ios

Beginners question:
I've made a new class that is a subclass of UIImageView.
How come that when i'm trying to create a method i cant use any UIView properties ?

```
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self = [super initWithImage:image];
    if (self) {
        UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGestureRecognizer= [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:<#(SEL)#>];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:rotationGestureRecognizer];

    }
    return self;
}


-(void) handleRotations: (UIRotationGestureRecognizer *) paramSender
{
    self.transform

}
```

The class cant recognise self.transform why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImage` doesn't inherit from `UIView`, it inherits from `NSObject`. You should subclass [`UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889) instead.

Have a look at the [UIKit Framework Class Diagram](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006955-CH1-SW1) to see classes inheritances.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. the subclass is from UIImageView. still nothing

Comment: That's really weird. I just tried and I could perfectly use the transform property...

Answer (score 1):

> is a subclass of **UIImage**
>
> i cant use any **UIView** properties

Because you need to inherit from `UIView` to use it's inherited properties or from `UIImageView`